# Rotary encoder connected to stepper driver

Tags: stepper-driver, rotary-encoder

I want to control the speed of a stepper motor using a rotary encoder ([OMRON E6B2 series](https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e6b2-c_ds_e_6_1_csm491.pdf?id=487)) conected to one of the PUL terminals of a [DM556S stepper driver](https://www.oyostepper.com/images/upload/File/DM556S.pdf).

¿Is that possible? ¿Which encoder type would be adequate? ¿How I can connect it? ¿Is it necessary to have more hardware like optocoupler?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I have the same Stepper driver, but I found a cheaper more elegant powerful solution without the encoder which is a safety feature when unexpected disturbances exceed your expectations. So it depends on your exact application and specs. **Would you like some assistance in defining the specs on your system? ** If important , I can. In answer to your ¿. (Yes, depends on specs, opto ¿ , not really but depends on SMPS noise interference on USB data if used due to EMI.

Comment: according to the manual of that DM556S it will work frecuencies between 200 up to 600 Hz, but my question is more about the electrical connctions and experience on that application

Comment: I see 2 components that are not connected in any way to each other except some motor and missing control.  I was describing the performance specs in hand-waving terms so you could focus on specs that MUST be defined before connecting any wires or even considering any other parts such as opto's.  Try to understand my answer and ask  better question with a well-defined application and expectations or considerations in the choices.

Comment: Your question lacks authenticity since the encoder costs $over $700 Cdn https://canada.newark.com/omron-industrial-automation/e6b2-cwz6c-1000p-r-2m/incremental-encoder-3channel-5/dp/12C1068 Is this a serious requirement? Why would you ask how to connect a $750 encoder to a $50 controller to a motor worth $25

Answer (score 1):

An issue is that the rotary encoder’s steps don’t necessarily match the stepper motor’s steps. Usually such encoders are used with DC motors, not steppers.

In contrast, unlike a DC motor, a stepper’s speed and direction are determined by the pulses being sent to the motor coils. If everything is working properly (that is, the motor doesn’t ‘slip’ or ‘cog’), you should only need open-loop drive: you have direct control over the motor by switching the coil drives in the sequence and rate you need.

Classic example: inkjet printer carriage drives generally use steppers without feedback, yet achieve exquisite position accuracy, just by controlling the coils.

Still, the rotary encoder can be used to monitor for faults, and provide an index (Z channel) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

### Rotary Encoder connected to Step/Dir stepper Driver

Yes, it is possible but you have to convert your A/B quadrature signals from the encoder to the Step and Direction signals required by your driver. This would give you position control.

It is simple to do, and here is a [link to one solution](https://www.twovolt.com/2018/04/23/quadrature-encoder-to-clock-and-direction-signal-converter-using-ls7084-ls7184/) using an LS7084 designed specifically for this purpose. The datasheet for the LS7084 is [here](https://lsicsi.com/datasheets/LS7083N_LS7084N.pdf), these are readily available at Digikey.
You could design this solution for either position or speed requirements.

You can also do this with an MCU such as the Arduino. The code is simple, and [here is a bouncing ball tutorial](https://www.brainy-bits.com/post/nema-stepper-motor-control-with-arduino-and-rotary-encoder) on making it work, though it's using a cheap and very low resolution encoder.

One of the easiest ways to do a speed control with an Arduino MCU is to use existing libraries:

1. There are several encoder libraries that give you position information for the encoder. You maintain a min to max count for your speed. Zero=stopped, and you can have one turn or multiturn count to your max value
2. Set the '[Tone](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/)' output to your desired output drive rate Pulses per second).
3. Feed the Tone into an input pin on the MCU and use interrupts to execute your driving code (Step/DIR). You could even use the Tone to directly feed the Step pin of your driver if you only ever have one direction of operation.

This is very minimal code, and should fit on any model Arduino, even an ATTiny variant. .

Comment: That will make the stepper motor position follow the rotary, OP wants the speed to follow the rotary.

Comment: @BenVoigt, then the OP would need to use the MCU solution.

Comment: according to the documentation of the OMROM E6B2 it can give you a square signal NPN, PNP from 5VDC to 24VDC; the control of DIR an ENA terminals on DM556S will be in charge of a PLC, no need to involve another hardware like arduino, when we alreay have chosen E6B2 and DM556S, the answer is moe about the adecuate connections to have it working

Comment: @user3177225, that's not what you said in your question. If you are using a PLC, then all you need is interface your Encoder to the PLC and write the code to set your speed.

Comment: It's a beginners show n tell but a Mickey Mouse example.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75,  that's exactly what I think the OP needed ....simplicity. If the OP had greater skills then I seriously doubt you'd get the same question.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to control the speed of stepper motor with a simple stepper driver. The stepper motor is fairly complex machine, not to be worth doing speed controller. It far more complex than induction motor, PMSM, BLDC so you would need a special electronics with a powerful DSP processor to make it working. As an example you have a company Trinamic that sells their drivers with dedicated motor, so custom made. No arbitrary motor can be hooked on electronics that is matched for dedicated motor.

These devices are to be used as open loop. You do set pulses frequency and the stepper should follow them, no feedback. If it stalls, then there should be a human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of rotation of the motor, using this driver, is proportional to the *rate* at which pulses arrive at the PUL+ and PUL− inputs. That's because each pulse causes rotation of a fixed amount.

The rotary encoder produces *position* information. That is, each unit step in its shaft *position* causes it to create a single quadrature pulse.

What you want is for the rotary encoder's position to correspond to motor speed, and this requires some conversion. That is, you require the *rate* of pulses applied at PUL+ and PUL− to be proportional to the rotary encoder's static position.

The rotary encoder you refer to is usually connected to some rotating shaft, as a means of measuring the shaft's angular position. This implies a closed loop, negative feedback system, to implement some kind of [servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism) behaviour.

From your question it's not clear whether that's the case, or whether you wish for speed to be *user* controlled; that is, the user turns the encoder shaft to set the speed.

In any case, using encoder position to determine motor speed is perfectly feasible, something a seasoned engineer might consider trivial. The complexity of the solution from your perspective depends entirely on whether you perform this "conversion" using discrete components (complicated) or in software using a microcontroller (much simpler).

Using discrete analogue and digital parts, one solution might require a module to translate the quadrature output of the encoder into a fixed analogue voltage. This would employ up/down counters and a digital to analogue converter, to produce a potential proportional to the encoder's position. This analogue signal would then control the *frequency* (rate of pulses) of an oscillator module, whose output is applied to the driver's step input (PUL). Such a module is called a "voltage controlled oscillator", VCO. This is clearly not a job for beginner without the time and the will to learn, and fail a few times.

That's why I recommend going with a microcontroller/microprocessor, like the ones you find in an Arduino, or Raspberry Pi, for which sensing of encoder signals, processing, and production of appropriate direction and step signals is trivial, and performed in software.

Such a solution might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbtw0X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I did this early 70’s to simulate control from an encoder hand wheel to remote machine slide. No undedicated plc’s available then and control had to be in real time because it was safety critical.Decoded Quadrature encoder output using cmos logic, which meant manufacturing the board by etching. The decode board was produced to provide an up/ down direction signal and a x1, x2, and x4 single pulse train outputs. The chosen pulse train and direction signals were the fed into a stepper controller and drive module, which operated the machine slide at a distance via the stepper motor attached to a lead screw. I had to service this machine recently as it is still being used.
A later version was retrofitted with a cnc control, and because safety factors precluded a motor change at the time, I needed to manufacture a voltage to frequency board to allow the cnc to control the stepper motor with its +/- 10v analogue output. So yes, it’s all possible and you can learn a lot from doing it, but there’s no need now with all the kit readily available. Still fun though.